# Classification not corresponding when saving a raster from WMS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, style, classification

In QGIS, I would like to save a WMS layer representing the pHx10(ranging from 0 to 140 https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map from ISRIC) using an area in Belgium as a map extent.

I saved the WMS layer using "save as", GeoTIFF as format, resolution of 1m and the selected map extent.
At first, the output really looks like a part of the WMS layer which is what I want. However, the values of the raster are divided into bands Red, Green and Blue, each of them having different values. When I perform a classification on the results, it gives totally different values from the WMS layer and I can not tell wich bands represents the pH and why the result is divided in 3 bands.

The first picture represents the WMS layer with normal pHx10 values. The second image is the saved raster with the right color but with the 3 bands (test_pH layer). The third picture is result of the classification when I use band 2 for example (values outranging pHx10 values).

How can I get a raster with the right pH values corresponding to the color/range of picture 1 and 2?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 3]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply right-click the initial (WMS) layer and copy the style, then paste it on the exported layer.

*The color settings (highlighted in red) are made automatically when copying the style:*
[image]